# add fonts and glyphicons to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an exact copy of this:
http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-shop-homepage/#

But now on my page I don't have fonts and glyphicons and it looks like this( you can see glyphicons stars are missing)
[image]

I've included bootstrap just copying bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js to vendor assets. I prefer this way, cause it feels more clear for me.
So I copied fonts folder from demo example to my app/assets folder, but it doesn't work.
What do I do?

Comment: is there no error, in console (Inspect element in browser) for missing files?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path for Glyphicons font. In bootstrap.min.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
.....
```